# DS18B20 OneWire Library with Raspberry Pi Pico W and Micropython

Tags: pi-pico, ds18b20, micropython

Good day,

I am using a Raspberry Pi Pico W with a temperature sensor among other things. I tried finding code online to make the temperature sensor work and it returns the following error.

```
Found DS devices:  []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in <module>
  File "ds18x20.py", line 1, in convert_temp
  File "onewire.py", line 1, in reset
OneWireError:
```

This is my code, does anyone know what is going wrong?

```
import machine, onewire, ds18x20, time
from machine import Pin


led = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
button = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
ds_pin = machine.Pin(16)
ds_sensor = ds18x20.DS18X20(onewire.OneWire(ds_pin))
roms = ds_sensor.scan()
print('Found DS devices: ', roms)

while True:
    
    ds_sensor.convert_temp()
    time.sleep_ms(70)
    for rom in roms:
        print(rom)
        print(ds_sensor.read_temp(rom))
    time.sleep(5)

    if button.value()==0:
        led.on()
        print('Door is open!')
        time.sleep(1)

    else:
        led.off()
        print('Door is closed!')
        time.sleep(1)
```

Thanks for reading. I don't have indent errors that might just be the StackExchange formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sensor can not be found, this is what is going wrong. Check the connections. Without further information it is not possible to answer why it is not found.

Comment: Yes thank you, I accidentally connected it to GPIO 18 instead of ground. This was the error.